# swift - chaining animation combined with UIView.transition

Tags: swift, core-animation, calayer, uiviewanimation

One more animation question.
What I need - to write a chain animation, for example:

1. image 1 shows 6 sec
2. change to image 2 with fade effect
3. image 2 shows 10 sec
4. image 2 scaling to 2 times for 1 sec
5. image 2 moves left for 1 sec
6. image 2 changes to image 3
7. image 3 shows for 12 sec

etc for 20+ images

So the result is a long chain of `.animate` and `.transition` with completion blocks, and it looks really awful.

And also duration time isn't working when I want only show image for 6 second - in about 1 second calls completion block with changing image lines.
Would be appriciate for any thoughts about my bug and situation in common.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0, animations: {
                self.imageView.alpha = 1
            }) { _ in
                
                UIView.transition(with: self.imageView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: self.images[0]) {
                        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                    }
                }) { _ in

               }}
```

Comment: I wanted to chain just 2 animations together using `UIView.animate` and feel your pain - nesting something like this will be ugly. Two thoughts. First, check into using `UIView.animateKeyframes` in your completion block. It actually made my code easier. Second, if you are able to use 3rd party libraries, this on looked promising. Written in Swift, uses `UIView.animate`, and fairly recent. Even if you can't use it, maybe it'll help you write your own version: https://github.com/icanzilb/EasyAnimation

Comment: I really tried `UIView.animateKeyframes`, but it isn't working with `UIView.transition`, which I use to fading image to another, just nothing happens